# How to do the binding in this case?

Tags: windows-phone-7

As the code below shows, I have a `Canvas` with a `TextBlock` inside. Next to it, two textBlocks, their text properties binded to LineOne and LineTwo, `ObservableCollection` variables. What I want is to create a binding which gives the date and change the color of the `Canvas` accordingly.

Theoretically, I can bind the date change for the `Text` property of the `DateTextBlock`. But I am not sure how to do the color change of the `Canvas`.

```
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
 <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
<Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="YellowGreen">
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock Name="DateTextBlock" Text="16 May" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
</Canvas>
<StackPanel Width="311">                                    
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Kindly advise me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Create  a colour property on the view model, and a property changed notifier. Bind the view attribute to the Colour property. In the viewmodel, when the text changes (or whatever it is you want to trigger the colour change), update the Colour property with the appropriate colour making sure to use the public property so that the change event fires.

Comment: Canvas.Background is not of type Color, you need to supply a Brush

Answer (score 0):

The `Canvas` `Background` property is of type `Brush`. Therefore, you are either going to have to bind a property of type `Brush` to `Canvas.Background`, or you can use a `ValueConverter` to convert a moel property to a `Brush`. See the examples on this page:

http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/useful-calue-converters